# Message "true" flashes on main page after session timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, timeout, cancan

I have a Rails4 app and I'm trying to flash a custom message when a session times out due to inactivity.

I'm doing this by configuring the `timeout_in` setting in `devise.rb`:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
  ...
end
```

and adding a custom rescue to my application controller:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  if user_signed_in?
    flash.now.alert = exception.message
    render text: '', layout: true, status: 403
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: flash[:alert] || "You must login first"
  end
end
```

Everything seems to be working fine... when the session times out, `flash[:alert]` already has the correct message so I just use that and when the user tries to access a resource without logging in first then the "You must login first" message is returned.

This is the code in the the main.html.haml page that renders these alerts:

```
.container
  .main-content
    #flash
      - flash.each do |type, msg|
        %div{class: ('alert alert-dismissable fade in')}
          %button.close{data: {dismiss: :alert}} &times;
          = msg
    = yield
```

The problem is that once a while I see a flash with the text "True" appearing right below the session timeout message:

[image: Message showing True]

and I can't figure out where it's coming from. It seems that something is creating a flash message with that value. I wonder what am I doing wrong or if there a better way to display a session timeout messages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try outputting the `type` of each flash – maybe Devise or something else is using the flash for other things than just messages. [Read more about using the flash for other things than messages.](http://thepugautomatic.com/2012/08/the-rails-flash/)

I wouldn't loop over all flash keys to render them – I'd explicitly render only the ones that are dedicated to messages (usually `:notice` and `:alert`).

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I'm not sure if the decision to have `flash` controlloing application state was a good design decision in the first place but that's how it works and there's nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a late reply, but this is what I did.

```
flash.each do |type, message|
  unless type.to_s == 'timedout'
  <!-- Carry on printing messages -->
```

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, here is the way that it was fixed

https://github.com/Casecommons/calico/commit/2c2580181e5746410d339c8d4c996002161cfdb3